# Regex: Key, Value multiple times, only if MAC is present

Tags: python, regex

How hard can it be??
I have the following line:

```
2021-05-25 14:54:11,517 INFO:[APP-MESSENGER] rx messages: meta_data=IfData={'dt': '12:54:11.516', 'meta':
BleDevice={'id': 0, 'name': 'CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04', 'rssi': -40}, 'header': Header={'timestamp': 56903198}},
len=10, msgs=[SysHeapInfo={'time': 56003295, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56103271, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56203247, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56303222, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56403198, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56503173, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,
...
```

In that line there are several same key, value pairs with the key `time` and `data_queue_free`

What I want is a 2D array with first column the value of the time key and the second value the data_queue_free key. But on IF the MAC (CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04) is present in that line

What I've come up so far:

`(?:CD:7C:2D:0E:D4:04){1}((time': (\d+))|(data_queue_free': (\d+)))`

Without the MAC it works fine, but then i don't have the MAC filter.

`((time': (\d+))|(data_queue_free': (\d+)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a two step approach, and first capture all the content after the MAC address `CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04` in group 1.

```
^.*?'CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04'([\s\S]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dqdI3q/1)

If that pattern is a too broad of a match, you could also limit the match to within the `SysHeapInfo=` part (assuming the data closes with a `]`

```
^.*?'CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04'[^][]*\[(SysHeapInfo={[^{}]*}(?:,\s*SysHeapInfo={[^{}]*})*)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cra1eM/1)

Then use the pattern with the two groups for *time* and *data_queue_free* on the group 1 value from the first pattern, and add for example the values to their own list.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/qby1Xm)

```
import re

s = ("2021-05-25 14:54:11,517 INFO:[APP-MESSENGER] rx messages: meta_data=IfData={'dt': '12:54:11.516', 'meta':\n"
            "BleDevice={'id': 0, 'name': 'CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04', 'rssi': -40}, 'header': Header={'timestamp': 56903198}},\n"
            "len=10, msgs=[SysHeapInfo={'time': 56003295, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56103271, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56203247, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56303222, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56403198, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "'data_queue_free': 50}, SysHeapInfo={'time': 56503173, 'free_heap': 22504, 'min_ever_free_heap': 22320,\n"
            "...")

firstMatch = re.search(r"^.*?'CD:7C:2D:0E:C4:04'([\s\S]+)", s, re.MULTILINE)

if firstMatch:

    data_queue_free = []
    time = []
    secondMatch = re.finditer(
        r"'time': (\d+)|'data_queue_free': (\d+)",
        firstMatch.group(1)
    )

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(secondMatch, start=1):
        if match.group(1):
            time.append(match.group(1))
        else:
            data_queue_free.append(match.group(2))

    print(data_queue_free)
    print(time)
```

Output

```
['50', '50', '50', '50', '50']
['56003295', '56103271', '56203247', '56303222', '56403198', '56503173']
```

**Note** that if the values in the data are always present and in that order, you don't have to use the alternation `|` but you could also match them in that order:

```
'time': (\d+),[^{}]*'data_queue_free': (\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Th4Szc/1)

Comment: Good use of 2 regex combined to get the desired output